# Connect my webapp to the facebook api and write fql query using jquery

Tags: facebook-fql

so far I am following the facebook doc to get started to connect webapp to facebook api. but i am lost somewhere.

```
"<script>"
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajaxSetup({
        cache: true
    });
    $.getScript('//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js', function() {
        FB.init({
            appId: '{app-id}',
            version: 'v2.5' // or v2.0, v2.1, v2.2, v2.3
        });
        $('#loginbutton,#feedbutton').removeAttr('disabled');
        FB.getLoginStatus(updateStatusCallback);
    });
});
"</script>"
```

1. where and how should i wright the fql query
2. what is the access token, does it changes over time for same page.
3. where should i give the access token to get the data from facebook.

Comment: What are you trying to do? What error you get? The access token is given to you when the user authorize your application, it usually don't expire for some time, you can find more info here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens

Comment: I am getting this error
    ReferenceError: FB is not defined
i wrote the above script after importing jquery library.
where should i write the fql query. to get data.
[link] (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/)

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer   
on this page. i have the access token and place to write the query. how can i write in my application

Comment: i suggest forgetting about jquery for a while and do that stuff with vanilla javascript. there is really no need to use jquery for those basic things. also, fql is deprecated since a very long time.

Comment: your question is way too broad, but here´s an article that may help you get started: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-login/

Comment: @luschn i followed the article you provided. on click of the button I am calling the method 
        function getUserData() {
     FB.api('/me', function(response) {
      document.getElementById('response').innerHTML = 'Hello '+response.name;
     });
    }
upon calling this i am getting this error
    ReferenceError: FB is not defined
        <anonymous>

Comment: are you trying on a real server or do you just open the html file? the error means that the javasript sdk is not loaded or initialized.

Comment: this is the jsfiddle link. 
https://jsfiddle.net/kranthikandi/e0dyxq51/
on running this getting this error --"Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains."--

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js" ></script>
</head>
<body style="background-color:#cfeae3;">
<script>

window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.init({
    appId      : '<your app id>',
    xfbml      : true,
    version    : 'v2.5'
});
};  
    (function(d, s, id){
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
function getData(){
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    if (response.status == 'connected') {
     city = $('#city').val();    FB.api("<query>",function(responses){

    }else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
    alert("not auth");
    document.getElementById('response').innerHTML = 'not logged in' ;
    } else {
    alert("not conne");
        document.getElementById('response').innerHTML = 'not connected';
    }
});
}

</script>
<div class="container">
<div id="tfheader"  align="center">
<input type="text" class="tftextinput" name="q"   id= "city"/>
<input id="btn"  class="tfbutton" type="submit"  onclick="getData()" />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```